# How do I redirect from ajax post to servlet to jsp?

Tags: java, jquery, eclipse, jsp, servlets

I'm doing the login for our system and the index.html has this script,

```
<script>
    $('#navbar').load('navbar.html');
    $('#errorMessage').hide();
    $("#loginBtn").click(function() { 
         $.post('http://localhost:8080/NewDesignV1/login.action',
            {
                username : $("#username").val(),
                password : $("#password").val()

            }
            ,'html');
    });
</script>
```

The post location is a servlet, I need to go to this servlet so I could get the data from index.html, manipulate it and redirect it to a JSP page.

My problem is, I can get the data from ajax post but it won't redirect to a JSP page when I use

```
request.setAttribute("key", value);
request.getRequestDispatcher("studentprofile.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Comment: what's happening after post?

Comment: it goes to servlet then it retrieves info from index but requestdispatcher doesn't work

Comment: you mean it still stays on the same page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that your have call it via `$.post` ,so it's an `ajax` method,
in fact `request.getRequestDispatcher("studentprofile.jsp").forward(request, response);` is working and you can get it

```
$("#loginBtn").click(function() { 
     $.post('http://localhost:8080/NewDesignV1/login.action',
        {
            username : $("#username").val(),
            password : $("#password").val()

        },
        function(data){
           console.log(data);//you can get the redirect jsp context
        },
        ,'html');
});
```

In order to let the `studentprofile.jsp` display,you need to avoid using `$.post`, you can create a form and then submit the form:

```
$("#loginBtn").click(function() { 
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    $(form).append("<input type='hidden' name='username' value='"+$("#username").val()+"'>");
    $(form).append("<input type='hidden' name='password' value='"+$("#password").val()+"'>");
    form.action="http://localhost:8080/NewDesignV1/login.action";
    form.method="post";
    form.submit();
    $(form).remove();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me :)